# Difference between portal-ext and portal-setup-wizard

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, portlet

I am new in using liferay, and i wil have to make an upgrade from Liferay6.1 to Liferay6.2.
I wont to know what is the utility of the portal-ext.properties if we can overide theme in the portal-setup-wizard.properties ?

Before doing the upgrade, i mooved all the properties to the portal-setup-wizard and al works fine.

In the 6.2 the portal.properties have some new properties and other new default values, so i am asking where do i have to keep the old properties in the ext or in the setup-wizard?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting up, Liferay first reads its own `portal.properties`. Then overrides with `portal-ext.properties` and last overrides (again) with `portal-setup-wizard.properties`. From that point of view, they're all equal. Just keep in mind that the last one wins. As it doesn't really make sense to have conflicting settings in the various files, I'd rather condense them into one.

The rationale behind `portal-setup-wizard.properties` is IMHO that Liferay never writes to `portal-ext.properties`, but needs some point to write the setup-wizard information to.

That being said, the counter-argument is that the setup-wizard actually writes the database configuration that you provide into `portal-ext.properties`, proving my statement above wrong...

If I haven't confused you: Just merge `portal-setup-wizard.properties` content into `portal-ext.properties` to have all of your configurations in one place. It doesn't make a big difference (unless you configure the same values in both files, see first paragraph)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't know that the portal-setup-wizard could be edited by Liferay good to know! i will try what you said to put all of my properties in the same file, but i prefer to put them in the portal-setup-wizard (more accessible).
Is it the only diffirence ? ^^

Comment: Writing to portal-setup-wizard.properties actually appears only once, during the initial setup. But funny enough - if you configure the database connection then, it will also write to portal-ext.properties... AFAIK the two files are equivalent apart from the order that I'm describing. Do as you wish and as you keep oversight. I prefer to have all of the settings in just one file.

Answer (score 0):

`portal-setup-wizard.properties` is for the first time/update setup wizard (as the name says). Values from there can be taken into the config database table.

`portal-ext.properties` are the overrides of last resort. Here you can override properties in production use.

Comment: I think the the properties are loaded from the portal.properties (in the port-impl.jar) then the portal-ext.properties and finaly the portal-setup-wizard.propeties (also the possibility of using the hook).
but i wont to know can i use only the portal-setup-wizard for the update and also for the overrides ?